# Node Mysql connection refused Errors: ECONNREFUSED, ETIMEDOUT, ENOENT

Tags: mysql, node.js

I created an application that takes input from an HTML form and inserts it into a MySQL Database. Everything was working perfectly until I started playing with Docker, SSH and NGINX for my study projects.

Here's my database.js file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myusername',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb',
    port: 3000,
    socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database connected!');
});

module.exports = con;
```

Now, whenever I run the server with

```
nodemon index.js
```

Server starts just fine but I get the database.js error:

```
    database.js:13
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

If I remove the pathSocket, I get the following error:

```
database.js:12
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

And if I remove the port, the following error shows up:

```
database.js:11
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

I looked everywhere on the Internet and tried everything, I even uninstalled the Ubuntu distribution (I'm using Win 10 with WSL 2) and reinstalled it. But the problem persists.

--

I believe it's a problem with the ports and so but I'm new to this networking fuss and I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo find / -type s` for search your socketPath, maybe the path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The error `Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is referring to your file's location. `ENOENT` means `no such a file or directory`.